# Why PostgreSQL returns more rows than expected?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I've next tables (only significant columns are shown):

```
clients: id, created_at
orders: id, client_id, created_at
```

**I'm trying to select all clients who has 1 order**.

```
SELECT c.phone, c.created_at, o.created_at
FROM clients c
JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.client_id
GROUP BY c.phone, c.created_at, o.created_at
HAVING COUNT(o.id) = 1
```

Getting 33k+ rows when I've only 27k clients.
What I do wrong?
What should I change in SQL?

Comment: Some clients have multiple orders.

Comment: Sure, I know it. But I need to select only clients with 1 order.
That's why using group/aggregate functions.

Comment: yes? and? Each order presumably has a different `created_at` date, so by your grouping rules, every order is a unique record, therefore has count of 1. in other words, unless you change your `group by`, your `having count()=1` is useless, because ALL of your result rows have a count of 1.

Comment: @MarcB so, looks like I need to replace join with subquery or ..?

Comment: no. just eliminate any grouping on the order table. all you need is grouping by client.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `c.phone, c.created_at, o.created_at` as your grouping. That statement will create unique groupings of those values. If a client has multiple orders, it will still return multiple values because you have included the `created_at` field from the orders table.

If you remove the `o.created_at` field from your `group by`, and use an aggregate function on it in your `select` (e.g. `MIN(o.created_at)`) you should be good to go.

Comment: I need this field in result.

Comment: @Miraage Your problem is that you are GROUPING by orders as well as by client.  Your grouping should only be `c.phone, c.created_at`.  In your select, you can get the `created_at` value by simply taking the min/max; i.e. `MIN(o.created_at)`

Comment: @AdamMartin sound nice, but what if client has more than 1 order?

Comment: @Miraage You're filtering for clients with only one order in your `HAVING` clause... The reason everyone was showing up for you before is that you were grouping by order as well as by client, so every row only had one order.

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem between details and summary scope: you want the details of the order (created_at), but the order you want is determined by and aggregate fact (count if o.id). Break up the problem into two parts: which client_ids have 1 order using just the orders table, then join the clients table onto that.

```
SELECT 
    c.phone, c.created_at, o.created_at
FROM 
    clients c
JOIN 
(
 Select
     id, client_id, created_at,
     count(id) over (partition by client_id) count_oid 
 From orders
 ) o 
ON c.id = o.client_id
WHERE o.count_oid = 1
```

Comment: This is way more complicated than necessary.  The answer is already provided as a minor tweak to OP's query.